# Read CSV file to MySQL with a Datetime column Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a csv file with numbers(doubles), strings and datetime. This is how the timestamp in the csv is `15-MAR-20 12.00.13.031000 AM`. I have a table in MySQL Database with following column. RowNumber(int), Timestamp(datetime), Amount(double), Transaction_Type(varchar). The table corresponds to the columns in the csv file. The csv file does not have headers or columns headers.

This is a sample of the csv

`1     15-MAR-20 12.00.13.031000 AM   23.123    TQWEE
2      17-FEB-20 13.00.13.031000 AM   23.123    QWEFE`

Now my question is

1. How do i read the time and convert it to datetime before writing it to the database.
2. How do I read the data in the csv file (mycsvfile.csv) and fil1 the table on MySQL whiles keeping datatype.

This is what i have done so far

`data['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'], format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')`

And here was the error i got

ValueError: `time data '1' does not match format '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p' (match)`

Comment: It seems to me that your code should work. Is there something else going on here? Maybe extra spaces in your columns or something?

Comment: That is my confusion too. i just cant figure out why it is not working

Comment: What you have provided is not a `CSV` file however. Maybe if you provide the actual `csv` text, someone can figure out what's wrong. As things stand, you have not provided enough for someone to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Column name'])
```

Comment: I have already tried that. I have updated the question please

Comment: No. Here is my Error  
`ValueError: time data '1' does not match format '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p' (match)`